# Why does javascript tells me "unexpected token ;"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple table in javascript using arrays in the main code that I've already declared but its keeps telling me the same error for this line of code-

```
function setTable();
```

The error is- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Here is my function-

```
function setTable() {
    var toTable = "<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><center><table border=1>";
    toTable += "<tr> <td>country</td> <td>gold</td> <td>civillians</td> <td>warriors</td> <td>wood</td> <td>metal</td> <td>land</td> <td>food</td> <td>happiness</td> </tr>";

    for(var i = 0; i < NumOfPeople - 1; i++) {
        toTable = toTable + "<tr> <td>" + country[i] + "</td> <td>" + gold[i] + "</td> <td>" + civillians[i] + "</td> <td>" + warriors[i] + "</td> <td>" + wood[i] + "</td> <td>" + metal[i] + "</td> <td>" + land[i] + "</td> <td>" + food[i] + "</td> <td>" + happiness[i] + "</td></tr>";            
    }
    document.write(toTable);
}
```

Comment: If you want to call a function, don't put `function` in front of it. Just do `setTable();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call Your function directly : `setTable();`

dont use the Word `function` before the call,
`function` is used only to declare a method .

=> [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wnv2hbko/)